# How do I communicate JSON data from a Mobile Application (client) to Ubuntu (Server, on virtualbox) and vice versa

Tags: json, ubuntu, operating-system, ip, virtualbox

What IP should I be using? Since my primary OS is Windows and I'm accessing Ubuntu through Virtualbox.